# Bootstrap accordion scroll to top of active panel heading

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, scroll, accordion

I'm looking for a code that scrolls up to the top of the currently active panel heading of my bootstrap 3 html/css accordion. The closest solution I've found on stackoverflow is the snippet of js below.

This snippet works fairly well, but when a panel heading gets clicked the page scrolls such that the very top of the panel content is flush with the top of the screen. Is there a way to modify this so that the scrolling effect will result in the panel "heading" (as opposed to the top of panel content area) being visible at the top of the screen?

```
    $(function () {
    $('#accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {
    var offset = $('.panel.panel-default > .panel-collapse.in').offset();
    if(offset)$('html,body').scrollTop(offset.top); }); });
```

Let me know if I should be sharing the bootstrap accordion html as well.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I used this and it works fine you can adjust the -20 after the .offset().top if you need to tweak it up or down a little.

```
$(function () {
    $('#accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {
        var offset = $('.panel.panel-default > .panel-collapse.in').offset();
        if(offset) {
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('.panel-title a').offset().top -20
            }, 500); 
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: It acts somehow funny with animation, but still it is working ;)

Comment: Is there anyway to make this scroll to the .panel-heading actually clicked? It's currently scrolling to the first one, not great on a mobile device.

Comment: @JamesWilson I have answered below on how to target the actual .panel-heading clicked :)

Comment: did anyone has freezing/flickering effect when your try to scroll using mouse after the animation has ended?

Comment: Anyway to make this javascript logic work for any panel, so that we don't have to hard-code in a scrollTop class name???

Comment: @gigelsmith I can confirm your code works in Bootstrap 4 but it breaks in BS5.  Any update you could provide would be welcomed.

Answer (score 12):

This is to target the specific .panel-heading clicked as per James Wilson's comment on the accepted answer.

```
$(function () {
    $('#accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {
        var offset = $(this).find('.collapse.in').prev('.panel-heading');
        if(offset) {
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(offset).offset().top -20
            }, 500); 
        }
    }); 
});
```

All I changed from gigelsmith's accepted answer is 'var offset' and the scrollTop's target.

Comment: Great solution @JWPersh!!!!! I just copy-pasted it AS-IS and it work perfectly!!!

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't get the answer above to work, perhaps I'm missing something but I can't see how the scrollTop line above relates to the currently opened accordion item so used the following code instead. Hope it helps someone else:

```
$(function () {
$('#accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {
    var offset = $('.panel.panel-default > .panel-collapse.in').offset();
    if(offset) {
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('.panel-collapse.in').siblings('.panel-heading').offset().top
        }, 500); 
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Your version is using the class selector '.panel-group' instead of the ID selector '#accordion'. The latter will only work if that ID is defined in your html, which isn't a requirement for the accordion.

Answer (score 1):

Always animate looks a bit too much so this is my version to only do the job when heading is over the visible part.
(note that I use a `data-accordion-focus` to apply the fix)

```js
$('[data-accordion-focus]').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {
    var headingTop = $(e.target).prev('.panel-heading').offset().top - 5;
    var visibleTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (headingTop < visibleTop) {
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: headingTop
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

Comment: If you are using version 4, just replace panel-heading class by card-header

Answer (score 0):

By using `.panel-default` as selector of `.on()`, you can scroll to the active panel.

```
$('#accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', '.panel-default', function (e) {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
    }, 500); 
});
```