# Bootstrap accordion, scroll to top of active (open) accordion on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I'm making a responsive site using Bootstrap and it contains accordions with a large amount of text, when you read to the bottom and click the next accordion, the large amount of text is collapsed and I'm left at the bottom of the page.

I found this useful code from [Bootstrap accordion scroll to top of active panel heading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21958933/bootstrap-accordion-scroll-to-top-of-active-panel-heading) but it scrolls to the top of all the accordions, not the specific one that is open.

#### JS

```js
$(function () {
    $('#accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {
        var offset = $('.panel.panel-default > .panel-collapse.in').offset();
        if(offset) {
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('.panel-heading').offset().top -20
            }, 500); 
        }
    }); 
});
```

How can this code be modified to scroll to the top of the currently active accordion?

#### HTML

```html
<div class="panel-group custom-padding no-sides" id="accordion">                
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">
            <div class="panel-heading custom-padding">
                <h4 class="panel-title text-uppercase">Short synopsis <i class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></i></h4>
            </div>
        </a>
        <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p id="game-deck"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>                       
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">
            <div class="panel-heading custom-padding">
                <h4 class="panel-title text-uppercase">Concepts <i class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></i></h4>
            </div>
        </a>
        <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <ul class="whatever" id="game-concepts"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>                      
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">
            <div class="panel-heading custom-padding">
                <h4 class="panel-title text-uppercase">Themes <i class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></i></h4>
            </div>
        </a>    
        <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body" id="game-themes"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse4">
            <div class="panel-heading custom-padding">
                <h4 class="panel-title text-uppercase">Notable locations<i class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></i></h4>
            </div>
        </a>    
        <div id="collapse4" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body" id="game-locations"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse5">
            <div class="panel-heading custom-padding">
                <h4 class="panel-title text-uppercase">Notable characters<i class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></i></h4>
            </div>
        </a>    
        <div id="collapse5" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body" id="game-characters"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse6">
            <div class="panel-heading custom-padding">
                <h4 class="panel-title text-uppercase">Full description <i class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></i></h4>
            </div>
        </a>    
        <div id="collapse6" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body" id="game-description"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can animate the scroll by getting the top of the 'target element' and then calling animate on the body..

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#target-element").offset().top
}, 1000);
```

modifying it to be something like this will help you achieve what you are after

```
$('.panel-collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {
    var $panel = $(this).closest('.panel');
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $panel.offset().top
    }, 500); 
});
```

source: http://www.abeautifulsite.net/smoothly-scroll-to-an-element-without-a-jquery-plugin-2/

complementary fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hjugdwbp/

---

*Edit: 2018-05-25*

### Bootstrap 4 Example

Using the accordion example at: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#accordion-example
I have modified the code to support cards.

```
$('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(e) {
  var $card = $(this).closest('.card');
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $card.offset().top
  }, 500);
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/agpkc4v2/1/

---

*Edit: 2019-07-18*

### I made it 'prettier'...

#### Bootstrap 3

https://jsfiddle.net/erutfgvn/

```
$('.panel-collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function(e) {
  var $panel = $(this).closest('.panel');
  var $open = $(this).closest('.panel-group').find('.panel-collapse.in');
  
  var additionalOffset = 0;
  if($panel.prevAll().filter($open.closest('.panel')).length !== 0)
  {
        additionalOffset =  $open.height();
  }
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $panel.offset().top - additionalOffset
  }, 500);
});
```

#### Bootstrap 4

https://jsfiddle.net/9p7f0hut/

```
$('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function(e) {
  var $card = $(this).closest('.card');
  var $open = $($(this).data('parent')).find('.collapse.show');
  
  var additionalOffset = 0;
  if($card.prevAll().filter($open.closest('.card')).length !== 0)
  {
        additionalOffset =  $open.height();
  }
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $card.offset().top - additionalOffset
  }, 500);
});
```

---

*Edit: 2021-04-20*

#### Bootstrap 5

https://jsfiddle.net/hLzg0n2y/2/

```
$('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(e) {
  var $card = $(this).closest('.accordion-item');
  var $open = $($(this).data('parent')).find('.collapse.show');
  
  var additionalOffset = 0;
  if($card.prevAll().filter($open.closest('.accordion-item')).length !== 0)
  {
        additionalOffset =  $open.height();
  }
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $card.offset().top - additionalOffset
  }, 500);
});
```

Comment: I can't see how this would work without having a different function for each panel with a unique ID?

Comment: Thank you, that was most helpful

Comment: I have wrapped my `.panel-group` in slimScroll, how to achieve same result?

Comment: I added a return false; below the animate because I have nested bootstrap collapse panels and it was bubbling up and moving twice leaving the user on the parent panel, but otherwise this worked for me and is just what I was looking for!

Comment: It's working well. If necessary, you can offset some scroll, which was necessary in my case.

Comment: For nested accordions, you need to add `.not('.collapse .collapse')` to the line which assigns `$open` or it'll calculate the wrong offset when a previous sibling has an opened expander within it. (Also, while this is the best I've yet seen, it does still produce visual glitches when the closing previous sibling is especially long. To fix that, I suspect I'll probably need some kind of serious hack such as locking the page height until the animation is over, then releasing it while being sure to keep the "before" and "after" frames looking the same.)

Comment: Oh, and you also need an `e.stopPropagation();` for nested accordions or it'll dispatch two scroll animations sequentially (at least, that's what it looks like), resulting in it lining up the parent card's header even if that means scrolling the child you clicked out of the viewport.

Comment: Correction: For some reason, the obvious problem with `.not('.collapse .collapse')` wasn't occurring reliably enough for my cursory testing to catch it. (It breaks the inner accordion's scroll in basically the same way it's trying to fix for the outer one.) The proper formulation is to pull part of the query out into `var $parent = $($(this).data('parent'));` and then do `var $open = $parent.find('.collapse.show').not($parent.find('.collapse .collapse'));`

Comment: This is awesome! If you need to add a little more offset for say, a fixed navbar, you can tack it on manually like `scrollTop: $card.offset().top - additionalOffset - 75` or be cool and get it dynamically.

Comment: @Michael I can confirm your BS4 code works in BS4, but sadly BS5 breaks it.  It would be great if you could provide a BS5 update. Thanks.

Comment: @JDW I have updated the answer. It is not as smooth that the others but it is functional. I will work on the smoothness.

Comment: The Bootstrap 5 version worked perfectly for me.  The only modification I had to make was the 'additionalOffset' value. ~thanks.

Answer (score 8):

***Update 2021***

As of **Bootstrap 5**, jQuery is no longer required. Here is a vanilla **JavaScript** solution of scrolling to the top of the open accordion item...

```
const accordionItems = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion-collapse')
const acc = document.getElementById('accordionExample')

accordionItems.forEach((el)=>{
    el.addEventListener('shown.bs.collapse',(e)=>{
        var scrollOffset = acc.scrollTop + el.parentNode.offsetTop
        acc.scroll({
            top: scrollOffset,
            left: 0, 
            behavior: 'smooth'
        })
    })
})
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/wTY0TBuliy)

Comment: Class `accordion-collapse` might be optional. Maybe this better:  `accordionItems = acc.querySelectorAll('.collapse')`

Comment: Replace `acc.scroll` with `window.scroll` method.

Answer (score 2):

I am working on a project that needed the same functionality. Came up with the following code. I added the variables for clarification:

```
$('#accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {

var panelHeadingHeight = $('.panel-heading').height();
var animationSpeed = 500; // animation speed in milliseconds
var currentScrollbarPosition = $(document).scrollTop();
var topOfPanelContent = $(e.target).offset().top;

if ( currentScrollbarPosition >  topOfPanelContent - panelHeadingHeight) {
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: topOfPanelContent - panelHeadingHeight }, animationSpeed);
}});
```

Comment: Really like this answer depending on your use-case. The accepted answer will effectively scroll every time, whereas this will only scroll if you can't see the top of the panel/button trigger. This is a much better UX on most situations imho.

Couple of small tweaks/things to watch out for: (1) Be careful using .scrollTop on safari/ipads (2) Be careful if you have a sticky header, you'll need to add that to the "subtraction' going on. (3) You may wish to add a bit more than panelHeadingHeight in this example, like *2 just so they get a little visual space above the button.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.accordion-button').on("click",function(event){
    var accordion = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
    window.setTimeout(function(){
      $('body,html').stop().animate({ scrollTop: accordion[0].scrollHeight}, 1000);
    },100)
  }
```

When the user clicks the accordion arrow button the following steps take place in the code above :-

1.An accordion variable is set to the parent node with class ".accordion" of the accordion button.

2.accordion[0].scrollHeight - find the scroll height of the accordion that is opened.

3.Using the animate option using scrollTop the page is moved to the scroll height of the accordion.

4.To ensure step 2 & 3 are done after the accordion is open the setTimeout function is used to time the code after the accordion is open. If in your case the accordion body is longer then you might change the value accordingly.Currently its 100 in the above code.

Comment: Please do add an explanation along with your code for a more complete and detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here with Vanilla Javascript.

After give unique ids (collapse-{{uniqueId}}) to the elements with the **accordion-collapse** class :

```
let accordionItemsToBeFocused = document.querySelectorAll("[id^=collapse-]");

accordionItemsToBeFocused.forEach((el)=>{
    el.addEventListener('shown.bs.collapse',(e)=>{
        window.location.href = '#' + el.id
    })
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let accordionItemsToBeFocused = document.querySelectorAll("[id^=collapse-]");
  accordionItemsToBeFocused.forEach((el)=>{
   el.addEventListener('shown.bs.collapse',(e)=>{
   document.querySelector('#'+ el.id).scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' }
  })
})
```