# Bootstrap scroll top accordion panel UNLESS open/expand all

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35992900/bootstrap-accordion-scroll-to-top-of-active-open-accordion-on-click) works great, except that it also scrolls when the "expand all" from [here](http://www.bootply.com/peFUdnwOpZ) is called (and then it scrolls to each of the opened panels). Bootply example [here](http://www.bootply.com/6HNPpVngO3).

How do I stop the scroll from firing on expand all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a variable using jQuery.data() to indicate when the accordion panels have been triggered by "Expand All", and then reset that variable each time any panel is `shown`.

```
$('.panel-collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {
    
  if ($(this).data('noscroll')!=1){
    var panel = $(this).closest('.panel');
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: panel.offset().top
    }, 500);
  }
  // reset noscroll data
  $(this).data('noscroll',0);
});
$('.accord-closeall').click(function(){
    $('.panel-collapse.in')
        .collapse('hide');
});
$('.accord-openall').click(function(event){
    //set noscroll data
    $('.panel-collapse').data('noscroll',1);
    $('.panel-collapse:not(".in")')
        .collapse('show');
});
```

https://codeply.com/p/UA8qXnQIaJ

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!