# Add and remove (toggle) collapse class for bootstrap tabs

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have created bootstrap tabs and added collapse functionality to those tabs.
Am expecting the below functionality,

1.whenever I click on the tab content should be opened.
2.whenever I click the same tab content should be hided if it is open or else no need to hide.

With the help of collapse option i can toggle the content boxes,but not able to get the same functionality.Some of the tabs are not behaving properly.

Is there anyway in angular to fix this by adding and removing classes?

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Dynamic Tabs</h2>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" ng-click="clickEvent($event)"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample1"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample2"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample3"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade">
      
      <p class="collapse" id="collapseExample" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
   
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      
       <p  class="collapse" id="collapseExample1">Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
     
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      
        <p  class="collapse" id="collapseExample2">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
          
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
     
       <p class="collapse" id="collapseExample3">Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
        
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
```

Can anyone help me to fix this? I request everyone to review my code and check the behavior of the tabs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already given this solution earlier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56575046/9380480). You can do this with Accordion. This works as per your requirement

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="accordion container-fluid" id="expandInfo">
      <section id="yello" class="py-5">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row ">
            <!--start featured video -->
            <div class="col-4 text-center">
              <span class="fa-stack fa-2x" style="font-size: 45px;">
              <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-file-video fa-stack-1x aria-hidden=" true></i>
            </span>

              <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#viewVideo">SEE VIDEO</button>
            </div>
            <!--end featured video -->
            <!-- start train -->
            <div class="col-4 text-center">
              <span class="fa-stack fa-2x" style="font-size: 45px;">
              <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i>
              <i class="fa far fa-handshake fa-stack-1x aria-hidden=" true""></i>
            </span>

              <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#whyUs">WHY US?</button>
            </div>
            <!--end train-->

            <!--start instruct -->
            <div class="col-4 text-center yellopos">
              <span class="fa-stack fa-2x" style="font-size: 45px;">
              <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i>
              <i class="fa fas fa-users fa-stack-1x aria-hidden=" true""></i>
            </span>

              <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#yourInstructor">MEET US</button>
            </div>
            <!--end instruct-->
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

      <!-- Collapsible Element HTML -->
      <!--start viewVideo  area -->

      <div id="viewVideo" class="collapse row mt-3 panel-collapse" data-parent="#expandInfo">
        <!--start single news  item -->
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3" style="width: 70%; margin: auto;">
            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/WVm3D9kqows"></iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <h4>Women's Self-Defense Course</h4>
          <p>This is a video of a Women's Self-Defense Class given at Sam Houston State University. While watching a video isn't as good as attending a course, there is still a lot that can be learned from watching this online course. If you practice the
            skills presented in the video you can improve your chances of surviving an attack.</p>

          <p>Click the play button to see a short clip of the class.</p>
          <div style="text-align:center">
            <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
              <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick" />
              <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="9NMATMUT2634Q" />
              <input class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg" type="submit" value="Buy Now - $20">
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--end viewVideo  area -->
      <!--start whyUs  area -->

      <div id="whyUs" class="collapse row justify-content-center mt-3 panel-collapse" data-parent="#expandInfo">
        <!--start single news  item -->
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <div class="embed-responsive">
            <img src="image/why-join-mousels-mixed-martial-arts.JPG" width="442" height="370" alt="Why join Mousel's Mixed Martial Arts Academy" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail rounded mx-auto d-block">
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <h4>Why you sould choose us...</h4>
          <p>Sharing knowledge and helping others reach their full potential is what we do best.
          </p>
          <p>
            The martial arts were originally aimed towards life preservation and self defense, but today people come to us from all walks of life, each with their own set of reasons for wanting to train at Mousel’s Mixed Martial Arts Academy. Some want to learn self
            defense, others want to fight competitively, some seek to become physically fit and others just want to have fun. Whatever the reason you chose, you will find others just like yourself studying at Mousel’s Mixed Martial Arts Academy.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--end viewVideo  area -->

      <!--start yourInstructor  area -->

      <div id="yourInstructor" class="collapse row justify-content-center mt-3 panel-collapse" data-parent="#expandInfo">
        <!--start single news  item -->
        <div class="col-md-4">

          <div class="embed-responsive">
            <img src="../images/tim-mousel-profile.jpg" width="250" height="376" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail rounded mx-auto d-block">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <h4>Tim Mousel</h4>
          <p>Tim Mousel is the owner of&nbsp;<a href="http://www.defend.net/">Mousel's Mixed Martial Arts
            Academy</a>,&nbsp;<a href="https://www.womens-self-defense.org/">Women's Self-Defense</a>, and&nbsp;<a href="https://www.edge-trainer.com/">The Edge Personal Training</a>.</p>
          <p>Tim has trained many of Houston's top martial arts instructors and has students he has trained compete at the highest levels of mixed martial arts competition including the <strong>Ultimate Fighting Championship</strong> (UFC), <strong>King of the Cage</strong>,
            <strong>Pride</strong>, national kickboxing and Thai boxing championships, amateur and professional boxing. Tim was also the Strength and Conditioning Coach for two-time world boxing champion&nbsp;<a href="http://www.reggiesweetjohnson.com/"
              target="_blank">Reggie Johnson</a>.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--end yourInstructor  area -->
    </div>
    <!-- end expandInfo -->
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.Is it possible to apply this functionality to my code?

Comment: @user7566666 Yes you can. Instead of `tab-pane` use `Accordion` . Please accept my answer if you feel that my answer was helpful. Happy coding :)

Comment: can you share full code of your solution in a codepen/jsfiddle?because am unable to copy full code from snippet.please