# Bootstrap accordion, scroll to top of active accordion on click without bouncing back?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I'm adapting a Bootstrap accordion and trying to move the clicked open accordion to the top of the screen.

I am using **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35992900/bootstrap-accordion-scroll-to-top-of-active-open-accordion-on-click)** solution

When I click on an accordion and another one is open above the clicked one moves out of the screen and then back into it. I do understand that this is because the first open accordion gets closed and the new clicked one moves into that place before it gets pushed down to the top of the screen.

It's in all the solutions on the post I've linked. Is there a way to click on an accordion and it just stays on top of the screen, even when the content before it is closed?

Here is the same problem shown: **[JSFiddle snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/erutfgvn/)**
click on item 2, scroll down, click on item 3 and item 3 goes off screen and bounces back. It would be so much nicer if it just stayed on top.

With little text it's fine but it looks not that good if there is loads of content in the accordions.

```js
$('.panel-collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function(e) {
        var $panel = $(this).closest('.panel');
        var $open = $(this).closest('.panel-group').find('.panel-collapse.in');
        var headerHeight =  $('.menu-container').outerHeight();
        
        var additionalOffset = 0;
        if($panel.prevAll().filter($open.closest('.panel')).length !== 0)
        {
              additionalOffset =  $open.height();
        }
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: $panel.offset().top - additionalOffset - headerHeight
        }, 500);
      });
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove the `animate` to prevent the page from scrolling?

Comment: @NiceToMytyuk I tried it and it does jump then to the right place instantly but no smooth scrolling anymore.

Comment: So you want it to scroll to the opened panel but not to hide the closed one right?

Comment: The closed one should be closed but the opened one shouldn't scroll too far up out of the screen before coming back down to top. Right now the to be closed one closes and the open one scrolls in its place before it goes to the top of the screen.

I just want the open one to move to the top smoothly and the one to be closed to be closed but not affecting the open one. Basically remove the closed element and not have a gap where the opened one jumps too.